# Как выгрузить в XLSX с несколькими листами?

Tags: lsfusion

В lsFusion с помощью оператора PRINT можно выгрузить печатное представление формы в формате XLSX. При выгрузке можно указать имя листа в создаваемой книге:

```
PRINT printSheet1 OBJECT o = o XLSX SHEET 'Sheet1';
```

Однако, если существует необходимость выгрузки данных на два различных листа одной книги - возникают затруднения. Конструкция:

```
LOCAL f = EXCELFILE;
PRINT printSheet1 OBJECT o = o XLSX SHEET 'Sheet1' TO f;
PRINT printSheet2 OBJECT o = o XLSX SHEET 'Sheet2' TO f;
open(f());
```

просто перезаписывает второй файл поверх первого.
Пока нашел обходной путь - записывать первый лист во временный файл с помощью WRITE, а затем добавлять второй с помощью WRITE APPEND, но что-то подсказывает мне, что должен быть способ проще.
Собственно, в этом и вопрос - есть у оператора PRINT опция (ну или другой простой и очевидный способ), позволяющая не перезаписывать XLSX-файл, а добавлять к уже созданному новый лист?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что PRINT это универсальный оператор вывода формы в графический формат, а понятие "листов" это особенность одного конкретного формата XLSX. Поэтому включать дополнительные абстракции в сам оператор PRINT все же выглядит не совсем правильно, на мой взгляд. Хотя в будущем возможно и придется.

Ну и решение с WRITE выглядит как минимум более универсальным (так как XLSX файл может появиться откуда угодно). И, на мой взгляд, не настолько сложным. Скажем мой код, когда мне пришлось столкнуться с такой проблемой, выглядел следующим образом:

```
exportReportXls(Organization o, DATE dFrom, DATE dTo) {
    FOR organization(Device d) = o DO { 
        PRINT reportOrg OBJECTS d = d, dFrom = dFrom, dTo = dTo, o = o XLSX SHEET 'Устройство ' + id(d) TO exportExcelFile;
        WRITE exportExcelFile() TO 'myfile' APPEND;
    }
    READ 'myfile.xlsx' TO exportExcelFile;
    delete('myfile.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: "> Поэтому включать дополнительные абстракции в сам оператор PRINT все же выглядит не совсем правильно"


Звучит логично, хотя тогда не совсем понятно, как в эту логику вписывается абстракция SHEET - дать имя листу можно и средствами JR.